# Use joi schema in swagger

Tags: swagger, joi

At node.js, I just started working with swagger, and I want to integrate the parameter-validation schemas I created using 'joi' - with swagger.
There's https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi-to-swagger but I don't understand how to use the generated object in swagger...

This is how I use swagger:

```
swaggerAutogen(outputFile, endpointsFiles, doc);
```

This is how I use joi-to-swagger:

```
const { swagger, components } = j2s(postVersionInfoValidator);
```

How do I integrate the swagger-output.json created in the first step, with the swagger object created in the 2nd step?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this

1. Generate the Swagger schema using `joi-to-swagger`

```js
import j2s from 'joi-to-swagger';

const { swagger: swaggerA } = j2s(joiSchemaA);
const { swagger: swaggerB } = j2s(joiSchemaB);
const { swagger: swaggerC } = j2s(joiSchemaC);
```

2. Add the generated schemas into the `swagger-autogen` options. Note the usage of `@definitions` instead of `definition`. This is to allow us to use the Swagger schema object generated from `joi-to-swagger` as is.

```js
import swaggerAutogen from 'swagger-autogen';

const outputFile = './swagger-output.json';
const apiFiles = ['./app.js'];

const doc = {
  info: {
    title: 'Your API',
    ...
  },
  '@definitions': {
    PayloadA: swaggerA,
    PayloadB: swaggerB,
    PayloadC: swaggerC,
  },
  ...
};

swaggerAutogen({ openapi: '3.0.0' })(outputFile, apiFiles, doc);
```

3. Add the Swagger comments into your endpoints

```js
app.post('/endpoint-a', (res, req) => {
  //  #swagger.summary = 'Perform stuff'
  /*  #swagger.requestBody = {
        required: true,
        schema: { $ref: "#/definitions/PayloadA" },
      }
  */

  res.send('A');
});
```